# ¿Cómo sumar a lo largo de filas?

Tags: r, funciones

Estoy intentando crear una función, digamos "genérica" para sumar renglones en una base de datos.

Mi idea es que la función "reconozca" los elementos numéricos en la base de datos y sume por renglones.

Supongamos que tengo los datos de la siguiente imagen:

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función tomaría a partir de la segunda columna y sumaría 2+3+3+6+4+2+0 y así sucesivamente.

El código que hasta ahora he escrito es el siguiente:

```
suma_renglones < - function (x) {
  y = integer(nrow(x))
  for (i in 1: nrow(x)) {
    for (j in 1: ncol(x)) {
      if (is.numeric(x[i, j])) {
        y[i] = y[i] + (x[i, j])
      }
    }
    y[i]
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, al aplicar la función, la columna designada para almacenar el resultado de la suma solo muestra resultados NULL.
Cualquier ayuda u orientación será muy apreciada.

PD: Sé que ya hay soluciones al respecto en otros lugares como se muestra en este [ejemplo](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Select-just-numeric-values-from-rows-td3256237.html), sin embargo, mi intención es hacer una función "propia".

Comment: Alejandro, para próximas oportunidades, te recomiendo organizar tu código. Busca cómo hacerlo en tu entorno de desarrollo o busca esta funcionalidad online. [ejemplo para organizar código Ruby](http://codebeautify.org/ruby-formatter-beautifier). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver, decís que estás sumando en una columna de la matriz original, pero no  estás haciendo eso, simplemente estás creando un vector con las sumas `y`, además recordá que tu rutina no puede modificar un objeto pasado por parámetro porque está fuera de su "scope", lo que sí se puede, es retornar una nueva matriz con la columna adicional y de última "pisar" el objeto original

Reformulando un poco tu código

```
suma_renglones <- function (x) {
    y=integer(nrow(x))
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
            if(is.numeric(x[i,j])) 
            {
                y[i] = y[i]+(x[i,j])
            }
        }
    }
    x["suma"] <- y
    return(x)
}
d = suma_renglones(d)
d
```

Retorno

```
        A        B       C N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8 N9 N10 suma
1  Apples  Bananas Peaches  9  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10   63
2 Oranges Kumquats   Plums  1  1  3  5  5  5  7  6  6  12   51
3   Pears    Kiwis  Grapes  2  4  6  8  5  6  7  6  9   1   54
```

Qué es lo que hacemos?

- Al finalizar los ciclos tengo un vector `y` que contiene la suma de cada fila
- Agrego a la matriz `x` una nueva columna "suma" con las sumatorias
- Retorno `x` ya que la función no puede modificar la matriz original, al estar fuera de su "scope"

Comment: Wow, muchísimas gracias. Encontré una solución que al aplicar la función crea una columna y. La posteo más adelante aquí mismo para que me puedas dar tu opinión. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tengo una solución usando `dplyr` y `tidyr` sin loops, por lo que debería ser más rápida:

Construyo un ejemplo con los primeros 2 renglones

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("employee_1", "employee_2"),
  day_1 = c(2, 19),
  day_2 = c(3, 23),
  day_3 = c(3, 18))

         x day_1 day_2 day_3
employee_1     2     3     3
employee_2    19    23    18
```

Primero tengo que "transponer" el dataframe, que lo hago con `gather` y `spread` para calcular la suma de cada columna, y después tengo que de vuelta transponer el resultado y hacer un `inner_join` con la tabla original. A lo último lo que hago es cambiar el nombre de las columnas y con el `select` ordenar el resultado para que la suma quede como última columna.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(var, val, 2:ncol(df)) %>%
  spread(x, val) %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum)) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  inner_join(df, by = c("key" = "x")) %>% 
  rename(suma = value,
         x = key) %>% 
  select(-suma, everything())

         x day_1 day_2 day_3 suma
employee_1     2     3     3    8
employee_2    19    23    18   60
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado Patricio;

La solución que diseñé fue esta:

```
    suma_renglones <- function (x) {
y= integer(nrow(x))
for (i in 1: nrow(x)) {
for (j in 1: ncol(x)) {
if(is.numeric(x[[i,j]])
{
y[i] <- y[[i]] + x[[i,j]]
}
}
cat (y[i], file= "temp", "\n")
}
temp <- cbind(y)
x <- cbind(x, temp)
}
```

Al compararlo con tu código, creo que al final no lo hice tan mal, ¿cierto? Sin embargo, tu solución es claramente mucho más limpia y eficiente. En verdad aprecio mucho el tiempo que te tomaste para ayudarme. Saludos de nuevo :)